# Fractional Distillation Fractions

Tags: distillation, petrochemistry

Currently, I am trying to remember the order of fractions within the fractionating column. However, I have found a contradiction.

[image]

[image]

Consider the above diagrams, both from reputable sources. The first diagram places lubricating oil above that of fuel oil. However, the bottom diagram places them the other way around. Which one is correct? Looking for a definite answer.

**EDIT**: I have found this contradiction so many times between various sources.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You may be in trouble with getting a definite answer. I don't think that either thing is really a fraction - they are rather products made from various stuff got in distillation, or even otherwise.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_oil  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_oil

Comment: Mention the sources because the text is not readable.

Comment: Googling fractional distillation of petroleum and going on images, you find the contradiction many times